# Why do i get an added 'i' character at the end of string while using .writelines() in Python ?

Tags: python

I used that python code to get 3 inputs and write to a file but when i looked at the file named output.txt under /tmp, i see an added 'i' at the end of string.To illustrate, when i give as input a,b and c , respectively i get such an input : a b ci .What can i do to fix this problem ?

```
    name = raw_input("Name:")
    email = raw_input("Email:")
    phone = raw_input("Telephone:")

    a=open("/tmp/output.txt","w")
    a.writelines( name+' '+email+' '+phone)
    a.close()
```

Comment: before writing the data to the file, try to print the `name+' '+email+' '+phone`

Comment: What do you want to be in the file?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work ?

Comment: What's your command prompt look like?

Comment: i just want to see according to my input such an output on the first line of output.txt : a b c . @Malvolio can you write your working code here ? i guess i escape something.

Comment: maybe you are storing your phone number as a complex number.  (just kidding)

Answer (score 1):

**I don't:**

```
$ cat >/tmp/t <<_EOF_
> name = raw_input("Name:")
> email = raw_input("Email:")
> phone = raw_input("Telephone:")
>
> a=open("/tmp/output.txt","w")
> a.writelines( name+' '+email+' '+phone)
> a.close()
> _EOF_

$ (echo "John Smith"; echo "nobody@example.com"; echo "123-45-678") | python /tmp/t

$ hexdump -C /tmp/output.txt
00000000  4a 6f 68 6e 20 53 6d 69  74 68 20 6e 6f 62 6f 64  |John Smith nobod|
00000010  79 40 65 78 61 6d 70 6c  65 2e 63 6f 6d 20 31 32  |y@example.com 12|
00000020  33 2d 34 35 2d 36 37 38                           |3-45-678|
00000028
```

Answer (score 1):

Either `phone` has `'i'` at the end or something later appends `'i'` to the file.

`.writelines()` accepts a sequence of strings. It works here by accident (any string is also a sequence of one character strings). To write a string to file you could use `.write()` instead. Add `'\n'` at the end if you need it; neither `.writelines()` nor `.write` append a newline for you.

Answer (score 0):

try print

```
print phone
```

to see if content of variable "phone" is your expected